# Ember 3.6.1 inject an unknown injection: 'service:-document' after upgrade

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I'm currently trying to update my EmberJS application which was originally on version 3.0.2. Firstly I've got the app running on 3.2. I then upgraded further and was greeted with
`Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:-document'` in my browser console.

The app builds successfully using `ember serve` but I only get a white screen next to this error, the stacktrace is also absolutely useless. The only mention of such an error is a github issue on `ember-wormhole` on a way older ember version and I don't even use this addon in my app. I've also realized that the app dies somewhere after `app.js` was executed but none of my initializers get called.

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "^7.8.3",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.6.3",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.6.1",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.7.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-array-contains-helper": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-auto-import": "1.3.0",
    "ember-bootstrap": "^3.1.1",
    "ember-bootstrap-datepicker": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-changeset": "^2.2.4",
    "ember-changeset-validations": "^2.2.1",
    "ember-cli": "~3.6.1",
    "ember-cli-active-link-wrapper": "^0.5.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^7.1.2",
    "ember-cli-code-coverage": "^0.4.1",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-lint": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^4.2.2",
    "ember-cli-icon-rating": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-cli-page-object": "^1.11.0",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^7.0.0",
    "ember-cli-sticky": "^0.6.4",
    "ember-cli-string-helpers": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-collapsible-panel": "^3.2.1",
    "ember-composable-helpers": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-confirm-dialog": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-countries": "^2.0.2",
    "ember-data": "~3.6.0",
    "ember-form-for-intl": "^1.0.6",
    "ember-i18n-iso-countries": "^1.5.0",
    "ember-keyboard": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-keycloak-auth": "~0.3.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-moment": "8.0.0",
    "ember-notify": "^5.2.0",
    "ember-pikaday": "2.4.1",
    "ember-power-select-with-create": "^0.6.0",
    "ember-qunit": "^3.4.1",
    "ember-resolver": "~5.3.0",
    "ember-route-action-helper": "^2.0.3",
    "ember-source": "~3.6.0",
    "ember-toggle": "^5.3.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "husky": "^2.3.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^8.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.7",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "prettier": "1.17.1",
    "qunit-dom": "^0.8.0",
    "ui-ember-slider": "github:ifad/ui-slider",
    "watchman": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.* || 8.* || >= 10.*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-slider": "^10.6.1",
    "ember-cli-update": "^0.27.1",
    "ember-intl": "^4.2.3",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "npm": "^5.7.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "to": "^0.2.9",
    "update": "^0.7.4"
  }
```

app.js:

```
import Application from "@ember/application";
import RSVP from "rsvp";
import Resolver from "./resolver";
import loadInitializers from "ember-load-initializers";
import config from "./config/environment";
import $ from "jquery";

window.Promise = RSVP.Promise;

const App = Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver
});

$.getJSON("/api/env_settings", function(envSettings) {
  config.sentryDsn = envSettings.sentry;
  config.keycloak.url = envSettings.keycloak.url;
  config.keycloak.realm = envSettings.keycloak.realm;
  config.keycloak.clientId = envSettings.keycloak.clientId;
  config.keycloak.secret = envSettings.keycloak.secret;
  config.helplink = envSettings.helplink;
  config.keycloak.disable = envSettings.keycloak.disable;
});

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);
export default App;
```

Any ideas where the cause of this problem lies?

**Quick update:**

I've also tried upgrading my app directly to 3.15.2 which resulted in the same error...

**Another update:**

The stack trace looks like so:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: Attempting to inject an unknown injection: 'service:-document' vendor.js:54143:15
    assert http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54143
    validateInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17702
    processInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16916
    buildInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16956
    injectionsFor http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16970
    create http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17036
    instantiateFactory http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16896
    _lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16828
    processInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16936
    buildInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16956
    injectionsFor http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16970
    create http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17036
    instantiateFactory http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16896
    _lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16828
    processInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16936
    buildInjections http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16952
    injectionsFor http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16970
    create http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17036
    instantiateFactory http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16896
    _lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16828
    lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16666
    lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:45312
    getDOM http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:163053
    updateDocumentLanguage http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:163000
    set http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:162810
    _set http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:34139
    set http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:34080
    CPSETTER_FUNCTION http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:31584
    _set2 http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:33493
    setLocale http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:162946
    init http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:162862
    superWrapper http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:48884
    initialize http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:47083
    create http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:47667
    create http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17092
    instantiateFactory http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16896
    _lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16828
    lookup http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:16666
    initialize http://localhost:4200/assets/frontend.js:8767
    runInitializers http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54873
    each http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73443
    walk http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73357
    each http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73287
    topsort http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73295
    _runInitializer http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54899
    runInitializers http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54871
    _bootSync http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:53180
    domReady http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:53080
    _run http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72991
    _join http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72967
    join http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:72684
    join http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:59338
    bind http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:59442
    mightThrow http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9158
    process http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:9226
```

Using `ember-inspector` on the working 3.2 version of the app, i tried to find the service:-document under container in services of the `ember-inspector`. I sadly couldn't find the service there either...

Comment: Run the *old* app (that one that works) and use `ember-inspector` to look for the `-document` service. Then find out from where it comes. Also the callstack from your error would be helpful. That can answer the question where that service is used. Maybe try to remove your lockfile (`yarn.lock`  or `package-lock.json`) and rerun `yarn` or `npm i`.

Comment: I've already deleted my yarn.lock and ran `yarn` a couple of times and it didn't help.
I added the stack trace now as well. Didn't get around to try the method using `ember-inspector`, but will once I get back to it. Will post an update as soon as possible :)

Comment: Added my findings to the question... sadly nothing there about the service.

Comment: Have a look where the stacktrace points to. Browsers may provide additional source map information. With that you can find out where the service was injected.

Answer (score 0):

As @Lux said, the stacktrace was the pivot point. There was one call to an `initialize` function by an `ember-form-for-intl` which is broken on that version. Thus I've just removed it and got it working.

Thanks a lot!!